# Weird shorcut of Qt Creator for Split view

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, shortcut-menu, shortcuts-app

Look the `Split` shortcuts of `Qt Creator` (installed from https://download.qt.io/archive/online_installers/3.1/).

[image]

What is that? Should I `Ctrl+E+2`? I tried, it doesn't work. Why the command isn't on the right side?

Then I tried to remap to another key like `Ctrl+Cmd+J`, also doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your shortcuts settings where you assigned ctrl cmd 3 ? I think text might be wrong.